# Losing Backbone this context in view class

Tags: backbone.js, scope, this

I'm having a problem with my `this` context being lost when rendering a nested view. Here's my code:

```
Workflow.Views.Wall = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName:    'div',
  id:         'wall',
  className:  'row-fluid span12',

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.model.view = this;
  },

  render: function() {
    this.model.stages.each(this.renderStage);
    return this;
  },

  renderStage: function(model) {
    var stageView = new Workflow.Views.Stage({ model: model });
    //this is DOMWindow
    this.$el.append(stageView.el);
  }
});
```

So a "wall" has many "stages". In my renderStage function, `this` is DOMWindow.

Anyone see my error?

Comment: Did you try putting `renderStage` in the `_.bindAll` function: `_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderStage');`

Comment: Hey @PaulOliver - that worked, thanks a lot. Now the 'this' is retained properly. Although, I'm not sure _why_ it worked. I thought the _.bindAll function just called the listed functions on any event... but I already call renderStage() from render(). Can you explain why it works?

Comment: Hey again @PaulOliver - I decided to RTFM. Got it now, thanks
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind your `renderStage` method to the `Workflow.Views.Wall` view...basically so you have the proper `this` context.

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderStage');
  this.model.view = this;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just call `_.bindAll` with no method arguments, which will automagically bind `this` to *all* methods:

```
_.bindAll(this);
```

For futher reading see [Understanding bind and bindAll in Backbone](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html). Also see the documentation for [_.bindAll](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll).

Comment: Latest version of Underscore (1.5.x) does not support bindAll without parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're using this in what I guess is a jQuery each() function. "this" refers then to the stage and not to the view anymore.
A simple workaround is to add this line a the beginning of your render method:

```
var that = this;
```

And then use "that" in your each() function.

Answer (score 1):

If stages is a collection, or rather, the each method is from underscore, you need to pass the context as the second parameter:

```
this.model.stages.each(this.renderStage, this);
```